# System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission Exception on New Deployment

Tags: asp.net, exception, web-applications

I have a friend that is moving a web application from one server over to another. The new server has the same settings as the first server, however, he's running into a Security issue. Here's the error details:

Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

The Event Viewer does not point to anything specific in the web.config file or anything. The web applicaiton is on the C: drive. This is a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 server with a brand new IIS 7 installation. IIS is set in classic mode for this app pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [changing the "Load User Profile" App Pool setting](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803211949/http://geekswithblogs.net/ProjectLawson/archive/2009/05/05/iis-system.web.aspnethostingpermission-exception-on-windows-7-rc.aspx) to True (the default is False)?

Comment: And I also changed the user to NetworkService. It's working now. Thanks!